# How can I resize an embedded image after applying a clipping mask in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

I've added a rectangle (step 1), placed an embedded image (step 2) and created a clipping mask (step 3). How can I resize the embedded image (in the example below, the image with the flag)? I use Photoshop 23.5.1.

---

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

[image]

Step 3:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the Move Tool <kbd>V</kbd>.
2. Select the image layer in the layers panel.
3. Click and drag a handle to rescale it.
4. If necessary, click and drag somewhere in the middle of the image to reposition it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Mylenium](https://community.adobe.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/7550029) on [community.adobe.com](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/how-can-i-resize-an-embedded-image-after-applying-a-clipping-mask-in-photoshop/m-p/13258583#M677239):

> It's just a layer that can be manipulated e.g. with the Free Transform tool like any other layer.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]